# Interpolate function in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, interpolation

Which are the equations used to interpolate a DataFrame in Pandas?

Reading the following link, I couldn't find anything related to them.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

I need exactly this:

[image]

But I'm not sure if the `interpolate()` function is doing the same thing. If that's the case, is there anyway I can change it to work like that?

**EDIT:** Example of dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 10, np.nan, 20, 17, np.nan, np.nan, 14, np.nan, 10, np.nan],
                  [5, np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan],
                  [3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, np.nan, 7, 8, 9, np.nan]],
                  columns=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `interpolate` method is NOT doing exactly that. However, it is still possible to achieve what you want.

**Short answer**

```
df.interpolate(limit=1).mul(~(df.shift(-1).isna() & df.isna())).fillna(0)
```

**Step by step explanation**

By default, the interpolate method treats the values as equally spaced. So if you input `[0,NaN,10,NaN,NaN,16]` for instance, you'll get `[0,5,10,12,14,16]`. This behavior is controlled by the `method` parameter of the interpolate function. You don't have to change it in your case.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, 10, np.nan, 20, 17, np.nan, np.nan, 14, np.nan, 10, np.nan], columns=["value"])
```

```
>>> df
    value
0     NaN
1    10.0
2     NaN
3    20.0
4    17.0
5     NaN
6     NaN
7    14.0
8     NaN
9    10.0
10    NaN

>>> df.interpolate()
    value
0     NaN
1    10.0
2    15.0
3    20.0
4    17.0
5    16.0
6    15.0
7    14.0
8    12.0
9    10.0
10   10.0
```

Now, the default behavior will replace any NaN, but you don't want consecutives NaNs to be replaced, so you need to use the `limit` parameter.

This parameter limits the number of consecutives NaN that will be replaced, but crucially, if you set the limit to 1, the first NaN of the consecutive NaNs will still be replaced; you don't want that!

```
>>> df.interpolate(limit=1)
    value
0     NaN
1    10.0
2    15.0
3    20.0
4    17.0
5    16.0
6     NaN
7    14.0
8    12.0
9    10.0
10   10.0
```

To get rid of those first values, you need to know which values are NaN and directly followed by another NaN. Use this :

```
>>> df.shift(-1).isna() & df.isna()
        value 
0   False 
1   False 
2   False 
3   False 
4   False 
5    True 
6   False 
7   False 
8   False 
9   False 
10   True
```

You can then multiply your dataframe by the negation (`~`) of this expression. (Note that `n*False = 0` and `n*True = n`)`

```
>>> df.interpolate(limit=1).mul(~(df.shift(-1).isna() & df.isna()))
    value
0     NaN
1    10.0
2    15.0
3    20.0
4    17.0
5     0.0
6     NaN
7    14.0
8    12.0
9    10.0
10    0.0
```

Finally, replace the remaining NaN values with 0, using `fillna`

```
>>> df.interpolate(limit=1).mul(~(df.shift(-1).isna() & df.isna())).fillna(0)
    value
0     0.0
1    10.0
2    15.0
3    20.0
4    17.0
5     0.0
6     0.0
7    14.0
8    12.0
9    10.0
10    0.0
```

Comment: If i may ask, for example, if we had a `df` with shape `(4, 11)`, how can this operation be made along columns, instead of rows? I tried using the argument `axis = 1` in `interpolate`, but the result is not correct. It's only correct for the first row, the other ones are wrong.